# Restrictions that comes from: If $(x, y)$ is a solution then $(-y, -x)$ is a solution too

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

If we have an equation like $f(x, y)=0$. And there is symmetry such that if $(x, y)$ is a solution then $(-y, -x)$ is a solution too, then what  kind of assumptions on $x$, $y$ can be made without loss of generality? Or what kind of maps can provide an easier equation?

I know that if $(x, y)$ is a solution and then $(-x, -y)$ is a solution too then we can solve for positive values only. Can you help me about above question?

Comment: Not sure if it helps much, but you can notice that $(x,y) \mapsto (-y,-x)$ is reflection across a line $x+y=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map $(x,y) \mapsto (-y,-x)$ is a involution (i.e. if you apply it to itself you get the identity map) and it gives you a correspondance between the two regions
$$\{ (x,y) : x+y <0 \}$$ and $$\{ (x,y) : x+y >0 \}$$
while it has as fixed points the line $x+y=0$. So, you have a symmetry with respect to this line, and you can consider WLOG $$x+y \ge 0$$